# What is a shape created by moving and rotating a primitive along a curve?

Tags: geometry, curves

So there is a primitive, or a number thereof; a primitive is a cuboid, a capsule or a sphere representing some simplified collision of an object. An example would be an apple simplified as a sphere, or a sword simplified as a cuboid.

It then is moved along a curve in 3D space; the primitives translate and rotate but don't change their scale. All the points where these any of the points of these primitives were along this curve forms some new shape; what would this shape be called and how can I analyze it?

I did utilize convex hull for this task but I'm sure there is another, more accurate and efficient representation of the shape created.

Comment: It is called a "tubular" shape.

Comment: If the primitive doesn't rotate, then up to an overall translation, it is the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of the primitive and the curve.

Comment: Thanks for the term @JeanMarie, it enriched my google searches :) Sadly tubular shapes led to me the term https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_surface that describes application for sphere-shaped primitives only; so cuboids and capsules are out of question. Is there any other point of reference for me to look for? Thanks